# Executing a function on a .txt file

Tags: haskell, ghc

I will try to explain this as clearly as possible since I'm a total noob with Haskell. I made a very simple program using the following code:

```
module Main where
main = interact (unlines . map reverse . lines)
```

When I run this and type `main`+enter and then a word, sentence or anything, I get it back reversed. Now I need to pass a .txt file to it. But I'm not able to do so. The assignment sheet I'm working from explains it like this:

> Compile the program (running it from the interpreter is not going to work correctly!), and run it, while redirecting the standard input to read from the file in.txt. On Windows machines this can be achieved using the command:
>
> ```
> Main < in.txt
> ```
>
> On Mac and Linux machines you need to use the command:
>
> ```
> ./Main < in.txt
> ```

This doesn't seem to work for me; when I type `Main < derp.txt`, I get the errors

```
<interactive>:3:1: Not in scope: data constructor 'Main'
<interactive>:3:8: Not in scope: 'derp'
<interactive>:3:13: Not in scope: 'txt'
```

What am I doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner so this question might be stupid.

Comment: Could you post the errors you're getting?  (I have a suspicion that you might be trying to compile from inside the interpreter, but without seeing the errors, I can't tell.)

Comment: my errors when i type Main < derp.txt are: 

<interactive>:3:1: Not in scope: data constructor 'Main'
<interactive>:3:8: Not in scope: 'derp'
<interactive>:3:13: Not in scope: 'txt'

Comment: You have to run that command from the command line, not from GHCi.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's what I'm doing. But I get no response :(

Comment: I'm opening the compiled .exe file and get a command line window opened. I enter the command there and get no response. That's what's happening right now.

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the executable ?

Comment: I am giving the command Main < "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\derp.txt". This should be good, right? But it just reverses the input I give.

Comment: That is where the file is, are you in the same directory as that (i.e. on your Desktop? Also, what is in your test file ?

Comment: the .exe and .txt are both in the desktop folder, yes.

Comment: try `type derp.txt Main`

Answer (score 4):

The commands to compile and run your program both need to be run from the *Windows* shell, and not from GHCi (the Haskell interpreter).  I don't use Windows myself, so I don't know first-hand how to get it open, but according to [this article on About.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsp/g/power-user-menu-win-x.htm), you can get a menu with a shortcut to the command prompt by typing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.  You may also have already opened it for other reasons, such as to launch `ghci` or compile your program; I don't know.

Once you've got the command prompt (also known as the shell) open, the interaction should go as follows:

```
C:\some\path> cd \path\to\haskell\directory\
C:\some\path> ghc -o Main Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
C:\some\path> Main < derp.txt
.pred si sihT
```

The errors you were getting indicated that you were running the command from inside GHCi; they were Haskell errors, saying that it couldn't find variables named `derp` and `txt` nor a constructor named `Main` (of course, `<` is just the less-than operator, and `.` is function composition, so those were fine).

Comment: Hi, this actually got me further :)! But now command line is telling me that it can't the file I'm giving it, which is strange because I'm giving it the right path.

Comment: @FrankKluyt: I'm glad to hear this helped!  As for your new error, though, we aren't psychic :-)  If you're getting errors, it helps us tremendously if you include what they are.  As it stands, all I can say is "are you *sure* it's the right path"?  Have you tried using `type C:\path\to\derp.txt`, which will print out `derp.txt` on the terminal?

Comment: I use the right path in terminal. But now it says permission denied :S

Answer (score 3):

You can also use runhaskell.exe:

```
runhaskell Main.hs <derp.txt
```

It works fine on Windows. Also you can omit `module Main where` and name your `.hs` file whatever you want, `Main.hs` name is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you compiled your program.

Compile it with

```
ghc -o Main FILENAME
```

where FILENAME is the name of the file.

This should create Main.exe on Windows and Main on Mac and linux

Comment: I compiled it now and I get an .exe file. However, when I give my program the input "Main < derp.txt", I get nothing back.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect operator should work. You can try using *cat* and piping the output to your program:

```
cat in.txt | ./Main
```

running on my machine (Mac) with a test file

```
hello
this is a test
```

I get back

```
olleh
tset a si siht
```

The redirect version also worked on my machine.

Comment: None of this seems to work for me. Surely I'm doing it wrong. Can I ask you to post the steps your taking to get this to work?

Comment: @FrankKluyt You should consider adding an exact transcript of your command line session to your question so we can see if you are doing anything incorrectly.